# Get a list of sorted names based on their average position in the google sheets table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table with people participating in a certain event over the week.
I need to get a list of these people that are sorted based on their average position in each column. The goal is to determine which people prefer turning up in the morning, later in the day, or in the evening.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

| Moday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sarah | Andy | Sarah | Sarah |
| Andy | Sarah | Andy | Andy |
| Blake | Max | Max | Max |
| Max | Blake | Karen | Blake |
| Karen | Karen | Blake | Karen |

Essentially I need to rank these people and then create a list of unique names based on their rank I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach:

1. Create a list of names with: `UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:C,1))`

Then with MAP you can go through each of the names, and with the help of BYCOL and XMATCH you can get the position in each column:

```
=LET(names,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:C,1)),
{names,MAP(names,LAMBDA(each,
BYCOL(A2:C6,LAMBDA(percol,XMATCH(each,percol)))))})
```

[image]

With AVERAGE you can find the desired value name by name:

```
=LET(names,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:C,1)),
{names,MAP(names,LAMBDA(each,
BYCOL(A2:C6,LAMBDA(percol,XMATCH(each,percol)))))})
```

[image]

And finally, you can sort by that column instead of showing it:

```
=LET(names,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:C,1)),
SORT(names,MAP(names,LAMBDA(each,
AVERAGE(BYCOL(A2:C,LAMBDA(percol,XMATCH(each,percol)))))),1))
```

[image]